# Why ucontext_t does not return to un_lick after executed?

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a coroutine, but in my code, I specified `ctx_main` for `uc_lick`, but after the execution of the subroutine `routine2` corresponding to `ucontext_t`, the program exits directly instead of returning to the `main` function to continue execution.

I have read the linux manual. According to my understanding, it should be possible to return to the `main` function after the subroutine is executed, but currently only `routine1` returns to main after the execution, and the program exits directly after `routine2` is executed.

And the exit status code is the return value of the last function in `routine2` (19, the return value of `printf`). Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

typedef void (*coroutine_func)();

#define STACK_SIZE (1<<15)

ucontext_t ctx_main;
ucontext_t c1, c2;

ucontext_t create_ctx(coroutine_func func, ucontext_t *ret_ctx) {
    ucontext_t ctx;

    getcontext(&ctx);

    char stack[STACK_SIZE];
    ctx.uc_stack.ss_sp = stack;
    ctx.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(stack);

    ctx.uc_link = ret_ctx;

    makecontext(&ctx, func, 0);

    return ctx;
}

void routine1() {
    printf("routine1 running\n");
    swapcontext(&c1, &c2);
    printf("routine1 returning\n");
}


void routine2() {
    printf("routine2 running\n");
    swapcontext(&c2, &c1);
    printf("routine2 returning\n"); // return value is 19
}

int main() {
    c1 = create_ctx(routine1, &ctx_main);
    c2 = create_ctx(routine2, &ctx_main);

    swapcontext(&ctx_main, &c1);
    swapcontext(&ctx_main, &c2);

    // Will not run to here, exit after routine2 is executed.
    printf("main exiting.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
routine1 running
routine2 running
routine1 returning
routine2 returning

Process finished with exit code 19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a variable after it stops existing.

```
ucontext_t create_ctx(coroutine_func func, ucontext_t *ret_ctx) {
    char stack[STACK_SIZE]; // allocated on stack
    ctx.uc_stack.ss_sp = stack;
    return ctx; // ss_sp is invalid pointer
}               // variable stack stops existing
```

You have to allocate memory with enough lifetime. For example:

```
char *stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
ctx.uc_stack.ss_sp = stack;
ctx.uc_stack.ss_size = STACK_SIZE;
```

How to check: compile with sanitizer options, they will help you debug your programs:

```
+ gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-clash-protection -fstack-protector-all -fstack-protector-strong -ggdb3 -grecord-gcc-switches -fcf-protection -O -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -fsanitize=address,undefined,pointer-compare,pointer-subtract /tmp/1.c
==1265711==WARNING: ASan doesn't fully support makecontext/swapcontext functions and may produce false positives in some cases!
routine1 running
routine2 running
routine2 returning
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
```

Comment: When I was debugging, I also reported "stack smashing detected" error, but I didn’t understand it, and then modified the code. Now I understand, thank you so much